# disable es6 features in Chrome 45.0.2454.93

Tags: google-chrome, babeljs

In the Chrome 45.x, a few features of ES6 are seems enabled by default, even those experimental flags are not enabled:

```
class Model {

constructor(properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}

toObject() {
    return this.properties;
}
}
```

is there a way to disable this? the reason is, I'd like to use transpiler babel to transpile code to ES5, with that ES6 disabled, I can do a more realistic test in the Chrome, possible? Thanks,

A.C.

Answer (score 4):

Open **chrome://flags/#disable-javascript-harmony-shipping** and Enable the feature. It will disable the harmony(ES6) features.

Comment: thanks, tried to enable the flag, the es6 code like let myvar = 1, still works. temporary solution now is, test the app in Safari to make sure app works in non ES6 browsers.